# Subtraction of 2 cells in different tables

Tags: mysql

I have very simple problem but I have no idea what can be wrong. I am trying to substract 2 int values, one from czasy.voice and second from webrtc.rozlaczenie. I want to save result in one of substraction cells. I have query:

```
update czasy set voice = ((select voice from czasy where idu = "2") - select rozlaczenie from webrtc where handshake = "a3u8duwexwf") where idu = "2"
```

And every time i get syntax error, both select works fine separately and gave me 
21 for first select and 4 for second select, so after query I should get 17 in czasy.voice

Comment: is there any relation between table czasy en webrtc?

Comment: "idu" is in both tables but there isn't any foregin keys

Comment: but what record from the webrtc table will be used? Or is there only one record in webrtc? Or how do you know the value of handshake to use?

Comment: It will be easier when I show it. 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9B06YvXPMPZLUtVUEdlWGh5dGs?usp=sharing

From webrtc I want rozlaczenie it is time of conversation in seconds, and in czasy i have time that you can use for talking. After conversation (every has it's handshake) i want to substract time that you used from time that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should approach from the handshake:

```
UPDATE webrtc
JOIN czasy ON  czasy.idu = webrtc.idu
SET czasy.voice = czasy.voice - webrtc.rozlaczenie
WHERE webrtc.handshake = 'a3u8duwexwf';
```

explained:

first we create a broad table, joining both the webrtc table and the czasy table. I use the idu columns in both tables for this.

Would you do that in a SELECT query, all columns could be seen. 
But now we use this to update.
One can access any column. Forexampe
`SET webrtc.foo = 12, czasy.bar = 42`

but of course also as a calculation like `SET czasy.foo = webrtc.bar -12`

And as the record with given handshake has an idu with value 2, it is clear the joined record from czasy has also idu 2

Comment: Omg, it works, thank you so much :) But can you explain me shortly why my way didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot about opening parentheses around `select rozlaczenie` part:

```
UPDATE czasy
   SET voice = (
         (SELECT voice       FROM czasy  WHERE idu = "2") -
         (SELECT rozlaczenie FROM webrtc WHERE handshake = "a3u8duwexwf")
       )
 WHERE idu = "2"
```

Comment: But there is "set voice = (( ) -  )" , so I thought it is fine, but I will check it

Comment: Now I get SQL error (1093) You can't specify target table 'czasy' for update in FROM clause